# Using animejs with webdriver > ReferenceError: NodeList is not defined

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, animejs

Using `webdriverio` to create a SaaS test. I'd like to add mouse animation using `animejs` so I can record the test to produce a how-to video.

In my `webdriverio` test (`addAdditionalUsers.spec.js`), I have

```
await closeBtn.animateMouse(); //line 34
```

I am importing `animateMouse` from `functions.js`:

```
export async function animateMouse() {
    await browser.addCommand('animateMouse', async function() {
        await this.waitForExist();
        const rect = await browser.execute(elem => elem.getBoundingClientRect(), await this);
        const targetX = rect.x;
        const targetY = rect.y;
        anime({                             //line 32
            targets: '#webdriver-mouse',
            left: targetX + 'px',
            top: targetY + 'px',
            duration: 1000, // Duration of the animation in milliseconds
            easing: 'linear'
        })
    }, true);
}
```

When I ran the test I received an error:

```
ReferenceError: NodeList is not defined
    at toArray (/node_modules/animejs/lib/anime.js:321:20)
    at parseTargets (/node_modules/animejs/lib/anime.js:644:87)
    at getAnimatables (/node_modules/animejs/lib/anime.js:649:16)
    at createNewInstance (/node_modules/animejs/lib/anime.js:845:21)
    at anime (/node_modules/animejs/lib/anime.js:933:18)
    at Element.<anonymous> (/test/includes/functions.js:32:14)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
            at Context.<anonymous> (/test/specs/addAdditionalUsers.spec.js:34:9)
```

I would like animejs to move the mouse to the `closeBtn` element.

**Update**

After changing `animateMouse()` to VonCs version, there is an error

```
Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style'), functions.js:32:9, addAdditionalUsers.spec.js:33:9).
```

Line 33 of addAdditionalUsers.spec.js is `await closeBtn.animateMouse();`

Line 32 of `functions.js` is from Vonc's `animateMouse()` function:

`await browser.execute((x, y) => {`

`addAdditionalUsers.spec.js` contains `import { createMouse } from '../../includes/mouse';` and `createMouse()`; on line 32.

`/includes/mouse.js` contains:

```
export function createMouse() {
    browser.execute(() => {
        var mouse = document.createElement('img');
        // console.log("test");
        mouse.setAttribute(
            'src',
            'data:image/png;base64,' +
            'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAQAAACGG/bgAAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAAAJcEhZcwAA' +
            'HsYAAB7GAZEt8iwAAAAHdElNRQfgAwgMIwdxU/i7AAABZklEQVQ4y43TsU4UURSH8W+XmYwkS2I0' +
            '9CRKpKGhsvIJjG9giQmliHFZlkUIGnEF7KTiCagpsYHWhoTQaiUUxLixYZb5KAAZZhbunu7O/PKf' +
            'e+fcA+/pqwb4DuximEqXhT4iI8dMpBWEsWsuGYdpZFttiLSSgTvhZ1W/SvfO1CvYdV1kPghV68a3' +
            '0zzUWZH5pBqEui7dnqlFmLoq0gxC1XfGZdoLal2kea8ahLoqKXNAJQBT2yJzwUTVt0bS6ANqy1ga' +
            'VCEq/oVTtjji4hQVhhnlYBH4WIJV9vlkXLm+10R8oJb79Jl1j9UdazJRGpkrmNkSF9SOz2T71s7M' +
            'SIfD2lmmfjGSRz3hK8l4w1P+bah/HJLN0sys2JSMZQB+jKo6KSc8vLlLn5ikzF4268Wg2+pPOWW6' +
            'ONcpr3PrXy9VfS473M/D7H+TLmrqsXtOGctvxvMv2oVNP+Av0uHbzbxyJaywyUjx8TlnPY2YxqkD' +
            'dAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
        );
        mouse.id = 'webdriver-mouse';
        mouse.setAttribute(
            'style',
            'position: absolute; z-index: 999999; pointer-events: none; left:0; top:0'
        );
        // console.log(mouse);
        document.appendChild(mouse);
    });
}
```

and the my webdriver test contains `createMouse();` on line 26.

`#webdriver-mouse` is created by `createMouse();` okay.

`addAdditonalUsers.spec.js` contains:

```
import Studio from '../../pageobjects/studio.page'; 
import { createMouse } from '../../includes/mouse'; 
import { highlight, animateMouse } from '../../includes/functions';

describe('Locking an Element', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {  
        // await browser.maximizeWindow()
        await browser.setWindowSize(1920, 1080);
        await browser.pause(3000);
        await browser.url('/login');
        await(await Studio.usernameField).click();
        await browser.keys('user@example,com')
        await(await Studio.passwordInput).click();
        await browser.keys('password');
        await(await Studio.loginSubmit).click();
        await browser.pause(6000);
    });
    afterEach(async () => {
        await browser.execute('window.localStorage.clear()');     
        await browser.deleteAllCookies();
        await browser.execute('sessionStorage.clear()');
        await browser.refresh();
        await browser.pause(3000);
    });
    it('Add Additional Users', async () => {
        createMouse(); //line 26

        // close the welcome screen
        await(await $('.cdk-overlay-container .cdk-overlay-backdrop')).waitForDisplayed({timeout:9000});
        await highlight();
        await animateMouse()
        const closeBtn = await $('.mat-dialog-container.cdk-dialog-container .close-btn-icon');
        await closeBtn.animateMouse(); // line 33
        await closeBtn.highlight();
        await browser.pause(1000);
        await $(closeBtn).click();
        await browser.pause(1000);
```

Comment: https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/issues/345

Comment: You're trying to run `anime()` in Node.js. It's not possible

Comment: Thanks @Phil. I'll have to keep an eye out for Anime.js v4, and try Tween.js in the interim

Comment: I think more detail is needed. see [mre]. Ex. you haven't given package.json or exact version numbers of the packages you have installed.

Comment: If the element with the id 'webdriver-mouse' is created successfully before the animateMouse() is called? Also, could you share the code where you are calling the ```createMouse()```?

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation `Is the element with the id 'webdriver-mouse' created successfully before the animateMouse()?` Yes, through `createMouse()`. I've added `addAdditonalUsers.spec.js` at the bottom of the question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Anime.js](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime) is primarily designed for browser environments and relies on DOM-specific objects and methods. This design poses challenges when attempting to use it in Node.js or React Native, where the DOM is not natively available.

While [issue 345](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/issues/345) does mention a V4 with Node support in early access, it is not yet generally available.

Using [Tween.js](https://createjs.com/tweenjs) (that you mentioned) instead, your `animateMouse()` function would be:

```js
import { Tween, Easing } from '@tweenjs/tween.js';

export async function animateMouse() {
    await browser.addCommand('animateMouse', async function() {
        await this.waitForExist();
        const rect = await browser.execute(elem => elem.getBoundingClientRect(), await this);
        const targetX = rect.x;
        const targetY = rect.y;

        // Using Tween.js for animation
        await browser.execute((x, y) => {
            const mouse = document.querySelector('#webdriver-mouse');
            const start = { x: mouse.style.left, y: mouse.style.top };
            const end = { x: x + 'px', y: y + 'px' };

            new Tween.Tween(start)
                .to(end, 1000)
                .easing(Tween.Easing.Linear.None)
                .onUpdate(function() {
                    mouse.style.left = this.x;
                    mouse.style.top = this.y;
                })
                .start();

            function animate(time) {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                Tween.update(time);
            }

            animate();
        }, targetX, targetY);
    }, true);
}
```

That does assume you have an element with the ID `#webdriver-mouse` in your HTML code.

You would use it with `await closeBtn.animateMouse();`

Comment: Thanks, VonC, this looks like just what I need. I still receive an error, added to the **Update** in my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Steve Good point. Maybe [Keyboard Corporation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21370707/keyboard-corporation)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77651207/6309) would help?

Answer (score 2):

When you do @VonC's version, the error thrown because it try to access a property of an object that is null because the element try to animate does not exist or is not yet available at the time when the `animateMouse` is called. The `browser.execute` runs scripts in the context of the browser and returns the result of the script. If the script does not return anything, `browser.execute` will return null.

So here, we need to make the `animateMouse` wait until the `#webdriver-mouse` is available before it starts the animation.

```
import { Tween, Easing } from '@tweenjs/tween.js';

export async function animateMouse() {
  await browser.addCommand('animateMouse', async function() {
      await this.waitForExist();
      const rect = await browser.execute(elem => elem.getBoundingClientRect(), await this);
      const targetX = rect.x;
      const targetY = rect.y;

      // Wait for the #webdriver-mouse element to be available
      await browser.waitUntil(async () => {
          const mouse = await browser.execute(() => document.querySelector('#webdriver-mouse'));
          return mouse !== null;
      });

      // Using Tween.js for animation
      await browser.execute((x, y) => {
          const mouse = document.querySelector('#webdriver-mouse');
          const start = { x: mouse.style.left, y: mouse.style.top };
          const end = { x: x + 'px', y: y + 'px' };

          new Tween.Tween(start)
              .to(end, 1000)
              .easing(Tween.Easing.Linear.None)
              .onUpdate(function() {
                mouse.style.left = this.x;
                mouse.style.top = this.y;
              })
              .start();

          function animate(time) {
              requestAnimationFrame(animate);
              Tween.update(time);
          }

          animate();
      }, targetX, targetY);
  }, true);
}
```

## Edit

> the mouse element is logged in the console fine. However, there is still the error Error: waitUntil condition timed out after 10000ms at Element. (.../includes/functions.js:32:7)

It seems that `browser.execute` is creating the element, but it's not visible to the script, so `browser.waitUntil` times out because it can't find the element.

As I see here, need to modify the `createMouse` to return a promise that resolves when the element has been created, then wait for this promise to resolve before calling `animateMouse`.

The below code expect to make `animateMouse` wait for the `#webdriver-mouse` to be created before trying to animate it, which should prevent the `waitUntil` from timing out.

In **createMouse()**,

```
export function createMouse() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
      browser.execute(() => {
          var mouse = document.createElement('img');
          mouse.setAttribute(
              'src',
              'data:image/png;base64,' +
              'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAQAAACGG/bgAAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAAAJcEhZcwAA' +
              'HsYAAB7GAZEt8iwAAAAHdElNRQfgAwgMIwdxU/i7AAABZklEQVQ4y43TsU4UURSH8W+XmYwkS2I0' +
              '9CRKpKGhsvIJjG9giQmliHFZlkUIGnEF7KTiCagpsYHWhoTQaiUUxLixYZb5KAAZZhbunu7O/PKf' +
              'e+fcA+/pqwb4DuximEqXhT4iI8dMpBWEsWsuGYdpZFttiLSSgTvhZ1W/SvfO1CvYdV1kPghV68a3' +
              '0zzUWZH5pBqEui7dnqlFmLoq0gxC1XfGZdoLal2kea8ahLoqKXNAJQBT2yJzwUTVt0bS6ANqy1ga' +
              'VCEq/oVTtjji4hQVhhnlYBH4WIJV9vlkXLm+10R8oJb79Jl1j9UdazJRGpkrmNkSF9SOz2T71s7M' +
              'SIfD2lmmfjGSRz3hK8l4w1P+bah/HJLN0sys2JSMZQB+jKo6KSc8vLlLn5ikzF4268Wg2+pPOWW6' +
              'ONcpr3PrXy9VfS473M/D7H+TLmrqsXtOGctvxvMv2oVNP+Av0uHbzbxyJaywyUjx8TlnPY2YxqkD' +
              'dAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
          );
          mouse.id = 'webdriver-mouse';
          mouse.setAttribute(
              'style',
              'position: absolute; z-index: 999999; pointer-events: none; left:0; top:0'
          );
          document.appendChild(mouse);
          resolve();
      });
  });
}
```

In **animateMouse()**,

```
export async function animateMouse() {
  await browser.addCommand('animateMouse', async function() {
      await this.waitForExist();
      const rect = await browser.execute(elem => elem.getBoundingClientRect(), await this);
      const targetX = rect.x;
      const targetY = rect.y;

      // Wait for the #webdriver-mouse element to be created
      await createMouse();

      // Wait for the #webdriver-mouse element to be available
      await browser.waitUntil(async () => {
          const mouse = await browser.execute(() => document.querySelector('#webdriver-mouse'));
          return mouse !== null;
      });

      // Using Tween.js for animation
      await browser.execute((x, y) => {
        const mouse = document.querySelector('#webdriver-mouse');
        const start = { x: mouse.style.left, y: mouse.style.top };
        const end = { x: x + 'px', y: y + 'px' };

        new Tween.Tween(start)
            .to(end, 1000)
            .easing(Tween.Easing.Linear.None)
            .onUpdate(function() {
              mouse.style.left = this.x;
              mouse.style.top = this.y;
            })
            .start();

        function animate(time) {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            Tween.update(time);
        }

        animate();
    }, targetX, targetY);
  }, true);
}
```

Comment: Good catch. Upvoted. Let's wait for the OP's feedback.

Comment: Thank you. I notice `#webdriver-mouse` is not being created by `createMouse();` in `addAdditionalUsers.spec.js` anymore. I recreated `import { createMouse } from '../../includes/mouse';` using autocomplete - the import statement is correct. There are no VS Code console or Chrome console errors about `createMouse()` - checking the browser Elements, there is no `webdriver-mouse` in the source code. It was working before moving from anime.js to tween.js, nothing has changed in `'../../includes/mouse';` since then.

Comment: I notice uncommenting out `// console.log(mouse);` in `mouse.js`, the mouse element is logged in the console fine. However, there is still the error `Error: waitUntil condition timed out after 10000ms at Element.<anonymous> (.../includes/functions.js:32:7)`. It seems the `mouse` being created by `mouse.js` is not accessible to line 32 in `functions.js` (i.e. the `await browser.waitUntil(async () => {
          const mouse = await browser.execute(() => document.querySelector('#webdriver-mouse'));
          return mouse !== null;
      });`

Comment: I edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks. The error is now `Error: waitUntil condition timed out after 10000ms at Element.<anonymous> (/.../functions.js:36:7) at Context.<anonymous> (/.../addAdditionalUsers.spec.js:34:9)`. Will `await browser.waitUntil(async () => {const mouse = await browser.execute(() => document.querySelector('#webdriver-mouse'));` work if the mouse is added using `document.appendChild(mouse);`?

Comment: Try add or increase timeout of *waitUntil* ```await browser.waitUntil(async () => { const mouse = await browser.execute(() => document.querySelector('#webdriver-mouse')); return mouse !== null;}, { timeout: 20000 });```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I receive an error `waitUntil condition timed out after 10000ms` produced by `await closeBtn.animateMouse();` even though `, { timeout: 20000 });` is set

Comment: Hi! Are you able to help me with this, please? (please see my last comment above)

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/7340), ```WebdriverIO.Element.waitUntil``` executes WDIO commands in async mode despite sync mode test context. Although this doesn't directly address the issue, it suggests that there might be some unexpected behavior related to how async and sync contexts interact in ```waitUntil```. So please make sure that the ```createMouse()``` has fully resolved before calling ```waitUntil```, do it by moving the ```waitUntil``` call into the ```then``` of ```createMouse()``` promise.

Comment: Here is sample how: ```createMouse().then(() => {await browser.waitUntil(async () => { const mouse = await browser.execute(() => document.querySelector('#webdriver-mouse')); return mouse !== null; }, { timeout: 20000 }); })````

Comment: Thanks! To confirm, this new code is to go into `animateMouse()`? When I replace `await createMouse()` with your latest code, the `await` in `await browser.waitUntil(async () => {const mouse...` gets flagged by VS Code `'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.` https://i.imgur.com/Mwowpvl.png https://i.imgur.com/pQLA0Fx.png

Comment: Can't you do ```await createMouse().then(() => {await browser.waitUntil(async () => { const mouse = await browser.execute(() => document.querySelector('#webdriver-mouse')); return mouse !== null; }, { timeout: 20000 }); });```??

Comment: No, the same flag on `await` in `await browser.waitUntil` is added by VS Code. If I remove the `await` from `await browser.waitUntil` there is no flag by VS Code, but running the webdriver test produces `Error: waitUntil condition timed out after 20000ms`